# prevent api's from using my custom log4j appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

This is what i have in my properties file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CA
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

And the log is like this -

```
428  [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore  - RAMJobStore initialized.
430  [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler  - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

430  [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory  - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
430  [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory  - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
430  [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler  - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
451  [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG com.myApp.tasks.util.TaskUtil  - Job scheduled
454  [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG com.myApp.tasks.util.TaskUtil  - Job scheduled
```

My question is  -

- Why DEBUG log is there if i set root logger to INFO ?
- How can i prevent other apis like quartz from appending logs.i want logs only by anything under `com.myApp`

Comment: Is that the _whole_ of your logging configuration or do you have other more specific `log4j.logger.com.myApp=DEBUG` type lines further down?

Comment: Re your second question, set the root logger to `OFF` rather than `INFO`, and just enable lower log levels for more specific loggers.